# Can a Buddhist own and run a billion dollar business?

Tags: ethics, modern-world

China, Japan, Korea, etc. have so many companies and Buddhism is widespread in those areas. My question is: can a Buddhist make the aim of his life to run a billion dollar business?

Answer (score 12):

Sure! It is allowed for lay people, as long as they observe [the five precepts](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/pancasila.html) and [virtue (sila)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/index.html), which includes [Right Livelihood (samma ajivo)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index.html). Please also see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8518/471).

The [Vanijja Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.177.than.html) states:

> "Monks, a lay follower should not engage in five types of business.
> Which five? Business in weapons, business in human beings, business in
> meat, business in intoxicants, and business in poison.
>
> "These are the five types of business that a lay follower should not
> engage in."

The [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html) states:

> The wise endowed with virtue
> Shine forth like a burning fire,
> **Gathering wealth as bees do honey
>
> And heaping it up like an ant hill.
>
> Once wealth is accumulated,
>
> Family and household life may follow.**
>
> By dividing wealth into four parts,
> True friendships are bound;
> One part should be enjoyed;
> **Two parts invested in business;**
> And the fourth set aside
> Against future misfortunes."

The [Dighajanu Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.054.than.html) states:

> "And what does it mean to maintain one's livelihood in tune? There is
> the case where a lay person, knowing the income and outflow of his
> wealth, maintains a livelihood in tune, neither a spendthrift nor a
> penny-pincher, [thinking], 'Thus will my income exceed my outflow, and
> my outflow will not exceed my income.'

The [Adiya Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.041.than.html) talks about the five types of benefits that can be obtained from wealth, which are summarized below:

> 'My wealth has been enjoyed,
> my dependents supported,
> protected from calamities by me.
> I have given supreme offerings
> & performed the five oblations.
> I have provided for the virtuous,
> the restrained,
> followers of the holy life.
>
> **For whatever aim a wise householder
>
> would desire wealth,
>
> that aim I have attained.**
> I have done what will not lead to future distress.'
> When this is recollected by a mortal,
> a person established in the Dhamma of the Noble Ones,
> he is praised in this life
> and, after death, rejoices in heaven.

Also from the [Anana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.062.than.html) which talks about "the four kinds of bliss that can be attained in the proper season, on the proper occasions, by a householder partaking of sensuality", summarizes it as follows:

> Knowing the bliss of debtlessness,
> & recollecting the bliss of having,
> enjoying the bliss of wealth,
> the mortal then sees clearly with discernment.
> Seeing clearly — the wise one —
> he knows both sides:
> that these are not worth one sixteenth-sixteenth
> of the bliss of blamelessness.

Billionaire businessmen can support society by creating jobs, fulfill the needs and wants of the people through supply for demand, and be philanthropists (similar to Bill Gates and Warren Buffett) who donate to charitable causes and also to Buddhist causes.

As pointed out by [Samana Johann](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/12162/samana-johann), [Anathapindika](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel334.html) is a great example of a very wealthy man in the time of the Buddha, who used his wealth to contribute to the spread of the Dhamma.

> Anathapindika had many carts filled with gold coins, and had them
> spread out upon the site. Finally only one small patch of ground at
> the entrance remained bare. He gave the instructions that more gold be
> brought, but the Prince Jeta announced that he was prepared to build a
> mighty gate-tower on that spot at his own expense. This imposing
> bastion and gate protected the monastery from the outside world,
> shielded it from the noises of the road, and emphasized the dividing
> line between the realms of the sacred and the worldly. Anathapindika
> then spent another eighteen million for buildings and furnishings. He
> built individual cells, a meeting hall, a dining hall, storerooms,
> walkways, latrines, wells, and lotus ponds for bathing as well as a
> large surrounding wall. Thus the forest glade was transformed into a
> monastery and stood apart as a religious sanctuary.

---

Addendum:

Added later to show the benefit of using one's wealth to give gifts to "the upright ones".

This is the story of householder Ugga of Vesālī, who gave a lot of gifts to the Buddha. The Buddha accepted them out of compassion. I only quote the final portion of the sutta here.

From the [Manāpadāyī Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/an5.44/en/bodhi):

> “Bhante, in the presence of the Blessed One I heard and learned this:
> ‘The giver of what is agreeable gains what is agreeable.’ Bhante, my
> couch spread with rugs, blankets, and covers, with an excellent
> covering of antelope hide, with a canopy above and red bolsters at
> both ends, is agreeable. Although I know this is not allowable for the
> Blessed One, this sandalwood plank of mine is worth over a thousand.
> Let the Blessed One accept it from me, out of compassion.” The Blessed
> One accepted, out of compassion.
>
> Then the Blessed One expressed his appreciation to the householder
> Ugga of Vesālī thus:
>
> > “The giver of the agreeable gains the agreeable,
> > when he gives willingly to the upright ones
> > clothing, bedding, food, and drink,
> > and various kinds of requisites.
> >
> > “Having known the arahants to be like a field
> > for what is relinquished and offered, not held back,
> > the good person gives what is hard to give:
> > the giver of agreeable things gains what is agreeable.”
>
> Then, after expressing his appreciation to the householder Ugga of
> Vesālī, the Blessed One rose from his seat and left. Then, some time
> later, the householder Ugga of Vesālī passed away. After his death,
> the householder Ugga of Vesālī was reborn among a certain group of
> mind-made deities. On that occasion the Blessed One was dwelling at
> Sāvatthī in Jeta’s Grove, Anāthapiṇḍika’s Park. Then, when the night
> had advanced, the young deva Ugga, of stunning beauty, illuminating
> the entire Jeta’s Grove, approached the Blessed One, paid homage to
> him, and stood to one side. The Blessed One then said to him: “I hope,
> Ugga, that it is as you would have wished.”
>
> “Surely, Bhante, it is as I had wished.”
>
> Then the Blessed One addressed the young deva Ugga with verses:
>
> > “The giver of the agreeable gains the agreeable;
> > the giver of the foremost again gains the foremost;
> > the giver of the excellent gains the excellent;
> > the giver of the best reaches the best state.
> >
> > “The person who gives the best,
> > the giver of the foremost,
> > the giver of the excellent,
> > is long-lived and famous
> > wherever he is reborn.”

Comment: i think your quotations are less unequivocal than your "Sure!" captures, but i won't downvote

Comment: i just mean, think of it this way. do we need to be billionaires to prevent calamaties for dependents, give supreme offerings, etc., or is some other aim at work there?

Comment: Billionaire businessmen can support society by creating jobs, fulfilling the needs and wants of the people through supply for demand and be philanthropists (similar to Bill Gates and Warren Buffett) who donate to charitable causes and also to Buddhism.

Comment: yes but who gets into business for philanthropic purposes?

Comment: **People get into business for their own livelihood**. As long as a businessman observes virtue/sila (Right Speech, Right Action, Right Livelihood), he would not be violating the Dhamma. If he has made more money than he needs, then he can enjoy one or more of the five benefits than can be obtained from wealth, which includes charity / philanthrophy.

Comment: i think you're oversimplifying. it has little do with the precepts, which few buddhists follow, anyway. all i mean to ask is if the super rich are motivated, to make money, virtuously, as in your quote above. i'm not saying the super rich are maras or anything, and i know that good karma can result in wealth.

Comment: Maybe Ruben likes to add a/the Billionars sample and life, next to Buddha, so very practical: [Anathapindika: The Great Benefactor](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/hecker/wheel334_en.html)

Comment: `Sure! It is allowed for lay people` Real Buddhism is not about `allowing` and `not allowing`. It's about controlling the mind.

Answer (score 6):

It is unlikely Buddhist practise can run a major corporation due to so many unethical things occurring in large business. For example, Apple was using cobalt from child labour in Congo; is said to engage in major tax avoidance; is said to engage in cheap non-Buddhist labour practises in Asia, etc, where employees are not treated as the Buddha taught in the Sigalovada Sutta.

The fact that many US businesses are now offshoring their activities in low-labour-cost & low-EPA countries shows unethical practises, namely, to enjoy the safety of US jurisdiction yet not support the US economy commensurately.

That the USA public debt just passed $20 trillion shows the unethical nature of large businesses because it shows a nation reliant on debt & a nation not earning sufficient taxation revenue due to low wages & relatively low corporate tax receipts. In the Anana Sutta, the Buddha said debt is unwholesome yet the business world revolves around making people & nations indebted.

Buddhist practise is based in meeting mutual responsibilities & obligations. This is obviously not occurring in the world of big business.

Comment: This is true. There are many examples. And also as you can see in life, you have to make many trade offs. But that does not exactly mean we cannot pursue matters as we see fit. I may be a Buddhist but I will do what’s needed about a situation at my workplace for example.

Comment: echo the alerting of unethical practices in corporate world. yet Apple the CEOs also other big Corps are not Buddhists. if saying Steve Job a Buddhist, it's more ludicrous than saying Superman Christopher Reeve indeed a super-human. one of the root problems of these un-checked unethical practices is they negated Karma and Rebirth, or they never heard about it. if death is the end of everything why not just have the maximum of what one capable? Capitalism is bred and groomed by Christianity, on one life then hell/heaven. -- Buddhism without Karma/Rebirth can do more evil than Christian faith.

Comment: What I feel is that, people are looking for a manual for leading their life. It doesn't exist. It is whatever you make of it. If we realize this much, then our lives will be a little more conscious.

Comment: I couldnt agree with you more here. The Isha Upanishad says at the very beginning RENOUNCE! That is the absolute oldest of religious doctrine in the history of our species tells us to forego attachment to material things. Shakyamuni Buddha recognized the need to part with materiality during his ascetic period. The mind cannot serve two masters as such.

Comment: This reads as: nice guys finish last. So if you didn't finish last you must be evil.

Answer (score 4):

I want to say "no", but it's not for me to dictate or question anothers' path. I couldnt. There is no way I could have all of that property and material responsibility and yet have no ego.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously there are lay Buddhists, even-though monks, mendicants, are traditionally not allowed to handle money at all.

Raga is one of the three poisons

> Raga (Sanskrit, also rāga; Pali lobha; Tibetan: 'dod chags) is a
> Buddhist concept of character affliction or poison referring to any
> form of "greed, sensuality, lust, desire" or "attachment to a sensory
> object

and whether the mega rich are greedy, or just rich, is probably a matter of opinion. It's probably a bit like asking can a communist be a a billionaire. No, but they can treat the rest of us as more than playthings.

Comment: You posted a bounty asking for a "canonical" answer. I'd say that [Anathapindika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anathapindika) is a canonical billionaire, I don't know what better/other example you might ask for.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is yes, that a Buddhist can be a billionaire -- a modern proof-by-example might be [Kazuo Inamori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuo_Inamori).

I don't have insight, though, into whether he made it "*the aim of his life* to run a billion dollar business" -- I imagine the billion happened as a side-effect of business, and wasn't the original business target when the businesses were founded, but I don't know -- there are probably biographies you could read.

Or, according to the Financial Times "[Kazuo Inamori, Kyocera founder, on altruism in business](https://www.ft.com/content/6089210a-3a45-11e7-ac89-b01cc67cfeec)",

> His conviction that material wealth is a byproduct of doing business with a deeper purpose has remained consistent — as has his desire to convert others to the same creed. “It is time to change the motivation system from greed towards money to other ways,” he says. “I didn’t want to be a rich person . . . My motivation has been making the people around me happy.”

Some advice, on philosophy and management, is published here: [Official Website of Kazuo Inamori](http://global.kyocera.com/inamori/).

---

Incidentally please don't comment that "[no true Buddhist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) could be a billionaire", or use my answer as an opportunity to disparage Mr. Inamori or his business.

---

There are also, and there have been, [Buddhist kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_kingship): people born to positions of wealth and authority (some of these might become monks instead, and so on).

There's also, for example, the story of [Tetsugen Doko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetsugen_Doko) -- who collected money and spent it.

So the trivial answer is "yes"; but maybe  you can't (or shouldn't) make it your "aim in life". A trivial answer to this topic might easy to misinterpret, though (like the Buddha's [not answering](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.010.than.html) when asked whether there's a self).

Incidentally a lot of the suttas you may read are for monks. I found it helpful to also read a book called *The Buddha's Teachings on Prosperity* which introduces and summarizes the Pali suttas which have advice for lay-people (for example [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/7760/254) was a summary of one chapter of it).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of Buddhists own big businesses. I suspect you are really asking whether a person who owns a big business can make progress in mindfulness meditation. It depends. He would have to be a good person and have an accurate understanding of the purpose of meditation. Ultimately, progress in meditation depends upon good karma, which is very difficult to define.

Answer (score 1):

Here are canonical verses answering this question;

> 'I have sons, I have wealth' —
> the fool torments himself.
> When even he himself
> doesn't belong to himself,
> how then sons?
> How wealth? [Dhammapada Verse 62](https://nanda.online-dhamma.net/tipitaka/sutta/khuddaka/dhammapada/dhp-contrast-reading/dhp-contrast-reading-en-chap05/#dhp062)
>
> The path to material gain
> goes one way,
> the way to Unbinding,
> another.
>
> Realizing this, the monk,
> a disciple to the Awakened One,
> should not relish offerings,
> should cultivate        seclusion
> instead.
> [Verse 75](https://nanda.online-dhamma.net/tipitaka/sutta/khuddaka/dhammapada/dhp-contrast-reading/dhp-contrast-reading-en-chap05/#dhp075)

There is traditional [non-canonical] [origin story for these verses](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=075)

As others have mentioned a wealthy householder Anathapindika, a banker, was proclaimed as foremost in giving and a Sotapanna. The story has it that he actually became poor at some point;

> ...
> Anathapindika and Visakha were not only the foremost donors in Savatthi (J 337, 346, 465), but their help was frequently solicited by the Buddha whenever something needed to be arranged with the lay community.
>
> Yet even the wealth of Anathapindika was not inexhaustible. One day treasures worth eighteen million were swept away by a flash flood and washed into the sea. Moreover, he had loaned about the same amount of money to business friends who did not repay him. He was reluctant, however, to ask for the money. Since his fortune amounted to about five times eighteen million, and he had already spent three-fifths of this for the forest monastery, his money was now running out. Anathapindika, once a millionaire, had become poor. Nevertheless, he still continued to provide some food for the monks, even though it was only a modest serving of thin rice gruel. [Anathapindika: The Great Benefactor](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel334.html#part2)

This wasn't the end of this story which is quasi-canonical at best but it goes to show that it's impossible to pursue both paths wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a question for good destiny as future rewards. But, having known life is momentary, death can come any time, which takes all his wealth in an instance, wise man use this life for utmost aim, total release.
The path to worldiness leade to death for sure, the path of Nirvana is another. The seeker after Nirvana even thrashes out Heavenly realm as equal as poison, as it is temporary destination, not lasted long, eventually bring back again to there, where he was!

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem lies when you enter into Buddhism or any other spiritual pursuit. You start to compare desires of your living in society, and desires of trying to find out what life is all about. You can guess which one is which.

Spiritual pursuits are for the person's inner nature. It calms and purifies some aspects of it. When we go outside and do things, we get stained in more ways than one but we can't help it.

I split these 2 things up on purpose.

But, tell me, can you imagine that you could pursue your spirituality, every moment, and still do whatever you are supposed to do outside in society as a responsible, good functional human being? It is possible, right? Then there's your answer.

Comment: that's why monastery life comes in. but the Buddha warned that by living on offering of other Buddhists, Bhiksus are in urgency to reach enlightenment, for a really enlightened being can do millions of good deeds for humans. Else these Bhiksus are in debt, they are also living on the merits of the Buddha, for the Buddhists in paying homage to the Buddha hence supporting the Bhiksus. But I'm really disappointed if I read books written by some Bhikkhus teaching Dhamma or meditation, not to mention if there issue about profit from book selling...

Comment: Well, I am not sure about the profiteering nature of some organizations. Maybe that's how they can conduct further programs? You never really know the true intentions. But if you fix your own intentions, then your next choices become clear. But nowadays our minds are not conscious of whatever is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Buddhists are endowed with the most precious things money can't buy. Buddhists own more precious things than the richest man on earth can. In fact a Buddhist can own the whole Universe and beyond. A billion dollar is nothing compared to the whole Universe.

Answer (score 0):

Billionaire super star Andy Lau in HK

Lau converted to Buddhism in the 1980s.[12] He was raised in a nominally Buddhist household and is now a follower of the Lingyan Mountain Temple in Taiwan.[13]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Lau

Best Male Actor Award Buddhism Movie - in this movie, Andy give up as monk due to his attaining the one of the psychic ability to see past life of sentients under the tree, a great distraction of life thereafter and he is In purpose to against the Buddhism perception to get rid this ability. It is implicitly told me why Buddha was still remain meditating under the tree till full enlightenment

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_on_Karma